# Alias directory minus one file

Tags: command-line, alias

I'd like to make an alias for a directory that contains many files.  If I open the aliased directory, I want to view all files except for one. New files will be added to the directory over time, and I want everything to be aliased except for the one file permanently not-aliased.

Is it possible to set this up without needing to run a script every time a file in the directory changes?

E.g.: myDir contains fileA, fileB, and fileC.

I want myAliasedDir to contain fileA and fileB, but not fileC.

Comment: I'm confused about the way you're using some of these terms. What do you mean to "open" a directory? What do you mean by "alias" a directory. Are you wanting to make physical copies of the files in that directory?

Comment: I'm trying to keep it simple without confusing users with the complexity of why I'm trying to do this.  I do not want copies. The directory is a project that I open in an IDE. If a file exists in a directory, the IDE behaves a certain way that is useful for editing. If the file does not exist in the directory, the IDE behaves a different way that is read-only but it is much more useful for viewing. I want to open two instances of the IDE (I can already do this). One instance will be the project that contains the file. The other instance will be the alias that does not contain the file.

Answer (score 0):

Can you get away with symbolic links?

Assuming your shell is bash:

```
$ shopt -s extglob

$ mkdir dir1 dir2
$ cd dir1
$ touch file{1..3}
$ ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 jackman jackman 0 Apr  1 12:40 file1
-rw-r--r-- 1 jackman jackman 0 Apr  1 12:40 file2
-rw-r--r-- 1 jackman jackman 0 Apr  1 12:40 file3

$ cd ../dir2
$ for f in ../dir1/!(file2); do ln -s "$f"; done
$ ls -l
total 8
lrwxrwxrwx 1 jackman jackman 13 Apr  1 12:41 file1 -> ../dir1/file1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 jackman jackman 13 Apr  1 12:41 file3 -> ../dir1/file3
```

Comment: My shell is bash.  Won't I need to run this every time another file is added to dir1?

Comment: Yes. If you want to create a link for any new file, you'll need to use something like `inotifywatch`